# Returning a Generic list and passing it to another method

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have wrote a small bit of code to scrape urls to a list.

```
public Parse(HtmlDocument doc)
    {
        List<string> top = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            HtmlNodeCollection node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='content']/ul/li/a");
            if (node != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in node)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Attributes["href"].Value);
                    top.Add(item.Attributes["href"].Value);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }

    public sub(HtmlDocument doc)
    {

    }
```

When I try to return the list "top" it is coming up with an error "Since 'ConsoleApplication1.go.Parse(HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument)' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression" The question which I am wondering is how can I return the scraped condense of the list top and them passing them into the method "sub"? Thank you for any advice you can provide.

Comment: Where are your return types for functions? public returnType FunctionName(HtmlDocument doc) { }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answers already say: You have to change the return type of your function too:

```
public List<string> Parse(HtmlDocument doc)
```

Then to pass it to sub you first have to extend the parameters of sub:

```
public sub(HtmlDocument doc, List<string> top)
{

}
```

Then in your code you can call the functions like this:

```
var top = Parse(htmlDocument);
sub(htmlDocument, top);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your function declaration to:

```
public List<string> Parse(HtmlDocument doc)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a return type for the method. So this:

```
public Parse(HtmlDocument doc)
```

Becomes:

```
public List<string> Parse(HtmlDocument doc)
```